# rect.hclust integer vector for "border" parameter

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

Clearly one can use an integer vector for the border parameter of rect.hclustL

```
x <- rect.hclust(foo, k=ncuts, which = c(2,7), border = 3:4)
```

So imagine I have ncuts and wish to have "pseudo"-unique coloring of each border cut:

```
x <- rect.hclust(foo, k=ncuts, which = c(2,7), border = 1:ncuts)
```

Clearly the border color list that is being selected is finite - but what are the actual colors?

I started looking through documentation and no leads there, I moved on to a cursory view of the source code - and nothing there either.

By observation I noticed the colors appear to be (limited to):

- Black
- Red
- Green
- Violet
- Light Blue
- Magenta
- Yellow
- White

But how are they defined - and more importantly say that I wanted to associate the cuts with the appropriate color later on - could I do it?

UPDATE:
The coloring of dendrogram borders when defined by a numerical color lists occurs strictly from Left to Right (Black, Red, Green3, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow Grey, Black, Red ...). The question then becomes - how can I associate / locate a cut's position within the dendrogram.

Comment: You can specify colors by number, which is limited as you show above, or by name. See [this](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf) for all the color names. The color numbers are black followed by the primary colors (red, green ,blue), followed by their compliments (cyan, magenta, yellow), followed by grey.

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward - I'm guessing that if you assign an integer vector >8 e.g. color=1:10 that the implicit color ends up being x mod 8; e.g. color=c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,1,2)

Comment: Try this: `barplot(1:20,col=1:20,names=1:20)`